# how to split a line on the base of dot in java?

Tags: java, regex

```
String line = in.readLine();

String document = "";

while (line != null)
{
    document +=line;
    line = in.readLine();
}
String words[] = line.split(".");

for(int i = 0; i < words.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

I want to split my `document` on the base of dot.

I tried using above code but it is throwing a `NullPointerException` at:

`words[] = line.split(".");`

Thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Did you mean - `document.split("[.]");`?

Comment: If you are planning to split on '.', try line.split("\\.").

Answer (score 2):

Your statement:

```
String words[] = line.split(".");
```

... inherently accesses a `null` object (`line`), since you're out of the `while` loop that iterated until `line` was not `null`.

Also, the `String.split` method takes a regular expression, so "." will not do, as it's the regex wildcard for any character.

Try splitting your line like this instead (escaped dot), once you've fixed your NPE:

```
String words[] = line.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 1):

The below statements

```
    String words[] = line.split(".");
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length;i++)
    {

          System.out.println(words[i]);

    }
```

should go within `while` loop

```
    while (line != null)
    {
          document +=line;
          String words[] = line.split(".");
          for(int i = 0; i < words.length;i++)
         {

            System.out.println(words[i]);

         }
         line = in.readLine(); // after the splitting, read next line
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When your code reaches:

```
String words[] = line.split(".");
```

it always will throw a NullPointerException, as `line` will always be null.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
words[] = line.split("\\.");
```